# Prove that $A \subseteq C$ if and only if $A\cup (B\cap C) = (A\cup B)\cap C$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I know that $A\cup (B\cap C) = (A\cup B)\cap C$ is true by
associative law

I think that $A \subseteq C = A \subseteq A^{c} + A$.

then I get stuck

Comment: Hint: show $(A\cup(B\cap C))\setminus((A\cup B)\cap C)=A\setminus C$.

Comment: I can't read your argument. What does $A^C + C$ mean? Why are you saying $A = C$?

Comment: what does \ means?

Comment: $X\setminus Y$ is $Y$'s complement with respect to $X$, i.e. $\{x\in X|x\notin Y\}$.

Comment: The statement just says that the power set lattice is modular, and any distributive lattice is modular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distributive law is $A\cup (B\cap C) = (A\cup B)\cap (A\cup C)$, which is a nice start for the exercise.  We will be done with the proof if we show that $A\subseteq C$ if and only if
$$ (A\cup B)\cap (A\cup C)=(A\cup B)\cap C$$

Every "if and only if" proof needs two directions, so start with assuming $A\subseteq C$.  Then $A\cup C = C$ and therefore the desired equation follows immediately.

For the other direction, assume $(A\cup B)\cap (A\cup C)=(A\cup B)\cap C$.  We need to show $A\subseteq C$ so for the subset proof, let $a\in A$.  Perhaps the easiest way to approach this is to assume, for contradiction, that $a\not\in C$.  Then $a\in A\cup B$ obviously and also $a\in A\cup C$, so we have $a\in (A\cup B)\cap (A\cup C)$.  On the other hand we have $a\not\in C$ and therefore $a\not\in (A\cup B)\cap C$.  Therefore $(A\cup B)\cap (A\cup C)\ne (A\cup B)\cap C$, contradicting the earlier equation.

Comment: elegant proof, thank you